# BIML AdoNetConnection with Oracle.ManagedDataAccess fails to validate

Tags: sql-server, oracle, ssis, ado.net, biml

I am trying to generate SSIS packages with BIML to load data from an Oracle (11.2) to the staging area of our DWH on SQL Server. 
I had no issues whatsoever creating the job in plain SSIS. However, using the exact same connection string on the AdoNetConnection node in BIML gives me the following validation error when I try to generate the SSIS packages:

> FlowFramework, Version=5.0.63316.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=015f370a62f9a1a3. Node ADO NET Source: Could not
>   execute Query on Connection ORA_TEST
>
> A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while
>   establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or
>   was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that
>   SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL
>   Network Interfaces, error: 25 - Connection string is not valid).

The wording "SQL Server" made me wondering if for some reason the specified provider is ignored (that if the error is piped through from the underlying provider).
I created a minimal example for testing purposes that's just a source-target mapping and reverse engineered it using BIMLExpress. The connection manager looks as this (I added the password part):

```
<AdoNetConnection Name="ORA_TEST"
    CreateInProject="true"
    ConnectionString="DATA SOURCE=XXXX:1521/XXXX;USER ID=XXXX;Password=XXXX;PERSIST SECURITY INFO=True;" 
    Provider="Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client.OracleConnection, Oracle.ManagedDataAccess, Version=4.122.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89b483f429c47342" />
```

The reverse engineered minimal example throws the very same error, even though the connection string and provider are identic to the ones I can see when I right click on the working (manually created) connection manager and click "View code".

Resorting to an OleDb connection is not an option in our case. We're using a managed SSIS runtime on Azure and failed to get the OleDb provider for Oracle working on it. The manually built package using the Ado.NET connection manager works, which is why I need to figure a way to generate the package with an Ado.NET connection and the Oracle Managed Data Access provider.

Any ideas how to fix this?

Comment: In short: BIML does not appear to function sufficiently with ODP.Net managed or even Oracle ODBC. It might work better with Oracle Attunity. But don't waste your time - if you have a scenario where you need to replicate a number of tables from Oracle to SQL, use Azure Data Factory pipelines with a hosted runtime. It has it's own quibbles but they aren't around drivers and data types. It just works.